# Normalization Techniques in Deep Learning

Tags: neural-networks, artificial-intelligence

I understand different Normalization techniques in Deep Learning eg. BatchNorm, LayerNorm, InstanceNorm, GroupNorm, but I don't currently understand which normalization technique should be used where.

Thanks.